# can I do this with pure SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
name          |order_id
=======================
first_record  | 0
second_record | 0
third_record  | 0
       [...]
```

I want to update just `order_id` with an incremented value (not sure how to put this correctly in english - feel free to edit with a better description). See expected output below:

```
name          |order_id
=======================
first_record  | 1
second_record | 2
third_record  | 3
       [...]  | n
```

I know how to do this either by using a script in some programming language or a sql procedure, both solution involve looping the whole table.

Comment: is it matter which name column have which order_id ?

Comment: Is there any other requirement other than straightforward oracle's rownum?

Comment: @safarov it doesn't matter which name

Comment: @cctan Just like rownum, but I want to update an existing set of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update table:

```
 SET @oo = 0;
 UPDATE table SET `order_id`=@oo:=@oo+1 ORDER By something;
```

Or just get order_id as returned row number while selecting:

```
 SET @oo = 0;
 SELECT name, @oo:=@oo+1 order_id FROM table ORDER By something;
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It works for mysql, now I need to figure out the syntax for hsqldb :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? The question is not that clear.

```
DECLARE @order_id int
SET @order_id = 0
UPDATE #tmp_Users
SET @order_id = order_id  = @order_id + 1
```